# NSMutable array containsObject, does it check the contents of the object or the object type?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am a little confused to how containsObject works. Does it check to see if it contains an instance of an object type or does it compare the inside of the objects variables etc to see if they match?

Comment: *Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object is present in the array.* https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:

Comment: It reads the documentation, to see what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an implementation detail, you can work on the basis that it calls `isEqual:` on each items and works on the result of that.

Under the hood it's probably calling `hash` on each item and comparing that, then, if the hash matches it will call `isEqual:` to make sure it's a real match.

Comment: but what does it mean for two objects to be equal? the same type or all the variables the same? for example if I have two message objects with different text inside are they equal?

Comment: That depends on whether you override `isEqual` (and `hash`) or not - if you have particular requirements then you should override. IIRC the default implementation just compares the pointers (it does not introspect on the properties you have added to your classes).